# LyX and Sagemath: Can't update/export from file using Sage module

Tags: lyx, sagetex

I have started to use LyX recently and enjoyed it very much. I became very interested in the possibility of integrating Sage(math) commands into the document. But then I became stuck, unable to export or update the document.

I'm using Windows 10 (10.0.19043.1415), Sage 9.3 and LyX 2.3.6.1.

Here's what I've done, following the instructions given [here](https://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Modules#toc8):

- copied the sage.module file to the LyX 'layouts' folder. After reconfiguring, the Sage module was available for selection in the 'Documents->Settings->Modules' menu.
- updated MikTeX and ensured the sagetex package was installed.
- opened the example.lyx file.

And here's the symptoms:

- All seems fine in the example.lyx document
- the 'View' and 'Update' buttons are disabled
- the 'Update other formats' button only enable LyXHTML
- If i try to export manually to any PDF format, I get the message: "LyX: Couldn't export file. No information for exporting the format PDF (pdflatex)
- If I remove the Sage module from the document, all export formats become available

See screenshot for ilustration.

It seems that a sagetex+pdflatex (or the like) export option should be available, but it's not.

[image]

Comment: Can you start LyX from the command line? There might be some output on the terminal that is helpful. Additionally, maybe open View > Messages pane and see if there is any helpful message in there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Nothing appeared on the terminal, but there were some messages on the Messages pane, the most relevant being:
frontends\qt4\GuiViewSource.cpp (345): Can't find format for backend sagetex!
(dialog-toggle progress)frontends\qt4\GuiViewSource.cpp (345): Can't find format for backend sagetex!

Comment: Good to know. Maybe you need to add a file format called "sagetex" under Tools > Preferences >File format. But I'm guessing the module was supposed to do that. So I don't know what to put for the settings.